# How to set default value of option to another argument in Python Click?

Tags: python, click, python-click

Is it possible to define an option's default value to another argument in click?

What I'd like would be something like:

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('project')
@click.option('--version', default=project)
def main(project, version):
  ...
```

If the option `--version` is empty, it would automatically take `project`'s value. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Is you code not working?

Comment: Yes, this is entirely possible, however you can't then use variables from functions in your `@click.option` - you'd need to define `project` before `@click.option`.

Comment: @YashKrishan no the code is not working

Comment: Is there an error? If yes, share it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try setting version to None. If the user sets it, it will be overridden, but if they do not you set it to project within the main function.

```
@click.command()
@click.argument('project')
@click.option('--version', default=None)
def main(project, version):
    if version is None:
        version = project
    print("proj", project, "vers", version)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example usage:

```
$ python3 clicktest.py 1
proj 1 vers 1
$ python3 clicktest.py 1 --version 2
proj 1 vers 2
```

To do this in the decorators, you can take advantage of the [`callback`](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#callbacks-and-eager-options) option, which accepts `(context, param, value)`:

```
import click

@click.command()
@click.argument('project')
@click.option('--version', default=None,
              callback=lambda c, p, v: v if v else c.params['project'])
def main(project, version):
    print("proj", project, "vers", version)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Yes but I would like a solution where everything is in the Click decorators and not inside the function